# How to reduce VPS mamory usage

Tags: wordpress, vps, ram

I installed new WordPress blog in VPS with 1 RAM of memory.

now its show that I used more than 80% of a RAM.

I don`t know what is the problem.

My website is new and It have little visitors !

Comment: this is my memory use:

httpd
web server
 
CPU: 0.6
Memory: 526 mb


named
dns server
 
CPU: 0
Memory: 99 mb


mariadb
database server
 
CPU: 0
Memory: 984 mb


fail2ban
brute-force monitor
 
CPU: 0
Memory: 628 mb

Comment: looks to me like fail2ban is misconfigured or not tweaked. Try this: https://fmos.at/2009/05/15/how-to-reduce-fail2ban-memory-usage/

Keep in mind that 1 gb ram is not enough for the long run. if your website is new I recommend you to start off with shared hostings (auto managed servers) that are dedicated to wordpress then later when your views increase you can move to vps or dedicated servers.

Comment: I turned off file2ban but the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not installed something based on web on you server end. For example, a web-based control panel, because that soaks up steep server resources.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.

Comment: Yes I installed VestaCP

Comment: That's it. To free up the memory, try to use a client panel that hooks to your server remotely.

Comment: Have you already find one? As far as I know, most of panels are web-based. If yes, please let me know the tool, If not yet, give [VPSrobots](https://vpsrobots.com/) a try, the one I am using that may help.